# How to respond to rejected edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, editing-help

I noticed a little while ago that one of my edits, which was ultimately approved, did have some rejections on it. I usually try to keep my edits short and I focus mainly on cleaning up titles that violate guidelines, such as when the user has appended tags to the front of the title, made grammatical mistakes, or had not properly capitalized it. Even with my edit notes, it has become apparent that some users glance over it and fail to see the purpose. My question is, is there a way to comment back on the rejection note, or is this a feature that has not been added? I think it would be helpful to explain my reasoning in some cases or v.v.

Comment: You say that you try to keep your edits short, but are you fixing everything that needs to be fixed in a post?  I quickly looked through some of your recent rejected edits and it seems like you might be skipping things that should also be fixed. Maybe instead of making short edits, fix everything and maybe people won't reject. As far as contacting/commenting, no, there is no way to comment back to those who rejected your edits.

Comment: ["**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: rejected edit? learn from it and move on

Comment: Hey, all the advice is great, but this isn't really a question about rejected edits. It's about whether or not there is a feature to respond to comments about rejected edits, but there is not. I am glad, however, to know that small edits are discouraged. That is my take-away here. I'd like to get better at helping.

Comment: I just found this and wish for it as well...  I made an edit that goes the OTHER way.  I'm pretty sure that the intent of the question is preserved, but, the original question was in trouble...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an example, I just reviewed your last pending edit:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10043875

What you did:

- Change a single preposition in the title.

What you ignored:

- Completely broken indentation in code.
- Fluff at the end: *Any help would be appreciated.*
- Tags.
- Bad title.

In the context, your single change just wasn't worth it.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the guidance. I will keep that in mind for the future. My thoughts were that it would be okay if I just focus my attention on one or two of a few aspects of what makes a good post. Besides, that does give others an opportunity to focus on other aspects. I will definitely pay more attention to the code indentation in the future though.

Comment: This does not answer the question "How can I reply" though?

Comment: @claus You respond by picking up your game. If needed after asking looking for guidance here.